# Need to give same color for Points and its label

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling

[image: like this I have to give]I have 10000 points, using Graduate Color I have given different color for each points in 10000. I want to give a same color for each label according to each points colors using ArcGIS. is it possible, How to do it.

the above image is model for my work

Comment: Do you want to assign each point a color based on a certain attribute?

Comment: yes I want give different color for each point, at the same time the point color and label color has to be same

Comment: Is the data dynamic, or is this a case where you could create the symbology once for that data set?

Comment: (DavidF) I have to create once as this that's all, then I can get the output.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I have the same problem, just less points, but still too many to change one by one

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh,

You can achieve this but not for thousands of individually coloured points. One would question if each point is uniquely coloured that your map is understandable?

Anyway to give a label a colour that is specific to the symbol look at the image below you should be able to work it out from there.

Duncan

[image: Defining classes for your labels]

Comment: I knew this way but I want to give unique color for each label based on the point color